# Share instance variable accross steps in Cucumber Ruby with Capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm new to Cucumber and Ruby and I want to check that data is visible on the page:

**Feature**

```
Given I am a user
And I own a thing
When I visit the page
Then I can see my thing
```

**Steps**

```
Given ("I am a user") do 
  @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
end

And ("I own a thing") do 
  @thing = FactoryBot.create(:thing, user: @user)
end

When ("I visit the page") do 
  visit page_path
end

Then ("I can see my thing") do 
  expect(page).to have_text(@thing.name)
end
```

**Result**

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
  
    expect(page).to have_text(@thing.name)
                                     ^^^^^^ (NoMethodError)
```

I've tried the following without success:

```
When ("I visit the page") do 
  visit (page_path($thing))
end
```

I understand that the instance variable is not availble to me on the page but I do not know how to inject it.

Comment: The instance variables should be available to you in other steps, they get set in the Cucumber `World` - are you sure the `create` isn't failing?  Also I wouldn't generally define the step with `And`  since that makes it seem like it could only be called with `And` (the words are technically all interchangeable)  -- instead define it as a `Given ("I own this thing") do ...`

Comment: Also check for typos, even in your above example you've got one "I own a thing" vs "I own this thing" - it's generally better if you post real code rather than example so people can see exactly what you're doing right/wrong

Comment: if I pp the variable immediatly after the create within the same step, the variable is printed to the console as an object, however if I pp thee variable on the next step it returns nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object was created through an association and needed to be accessed through it's parent so in my case @user.thing was the solution.